# Media Query Landscape not Working

Tags: media-queries

I am trying to make an application that is responsive to a full screen computer size and portrait and landscape sizing on a phone. I can get the full screen and portrait sizing to work, but when I switch to landscape, the landscape css media query does not work. Any ideas on what is going on? Here is my css:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation: portrait)and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      .landing-header {
          margin-top: 18%;
      }
      .landing-h {
          font-size: 145px;
      }
      .auth-box {
            position: absolute;
            top: 58%;
            left: 35%;
            margin-left: -15rem;
            margin-top: -26.5rem;
            width: 60rem;
            height: 80rem;
            overflow: hidden;
      }
      .user-auth {
          padding-top: 35%;
      }

      .greeting {
        margin-top: 6%;
        margin-left: 7%;
        font-size: 35px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .login-form, .register-form {
          font-size: 40px;
      }


      .login-form input, .register-form input {
          margin: 3%;
      }

      .landing-button {
          margin: 2%;
          width: 50%;
          font-size: 60px;
      }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 667px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
        .landing-header {
            margin-top: 9%;
        }
        .auth-box {
            position: absolute;
            top: 98%;
            left: 35%;
            margin-left: -22rem;
            margin-top: -26.5rem;
            width: 72rem;
            height: 20rem;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .greeting {
            margin-left: 34%;
            margin-top: 2%;
            margin-bottom: 1%;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
}
    }
      .user-auth {
        padding-top: 9%;
    }
    .landing-button {
        margin: 0%;
        width: 12%;
        font-size: 16px;
}
    .login-form, .register-form {
          font-size: 18px;
      }
      .login-form input, .register-form input {
          margin: 2%;
      }


@media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) and (max-device-width: 1600px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
    .auth-box {
        width: 61rem;
        height: 18rem;
        top: 95%;
        left: 40%;
        height: 23rem;
    }
    .landing-button {
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 18%;
        margin: 1%;
    }
    .greeting {
        margin-left: 30%;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    .login-form input, .register-form input {
          margin-top: 6%;
          margin-bottom: 1%;
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that your landscape media query currently has the same value for min and max width? If you don't, this may be your problem.

Comment: Good catch! I changed the min width, but no cigar. Even though full size and landscape are now working portrait is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I see what's biting you. In addition to the max and min being the same as I'd pointed out in the comments, somewhat counter-intuitively you need to use the same width & height values for both portrait and landscape modes. So, a device like the iPhone is always going to have a smaller value for its device width than its device height as its "native" orientation is portrait. If you make your width media query for the landscape mode match what you've got for portrait, it'll likely do what you want.